# How to display the date underneath posts on home page?

Tags: php, css, date

new to coding. Thanks in advance for your help :)

I've gotten the date to display on posts after they've been clicked (one post on a single page) but it won't show up on the main page with all the posts.

How do I apply it to posts on the main/front/home page?
How do I modify it in CSS? (change color or font, for instance)

This is in the functions.php:

```
function add_after_post_content($content) {
    if(!is_feed() && !is_front_page() && !is_home() && is_singular() && is_main_query()) {
        $content .= '<p> Posted '.date('F j, Y').'&nbsp;'.'</p>';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_after_post_content');
```

Comment: are you talking about Wordpress? You should mention that in your question and add it as a tag...

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP in `functions.php`, try changing to this:

```
function add_after_post_content($content) {
    if(!is_feed() && is_singular() && is_main_query()) {
        $content .= '<p> Posted '.date('F j, Y').'&nbsp;'.'</p>';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_after_post_content');
```

Basically, the second line of that function uses `!is_front_page() && !is_home()` to say "if NOT the home page and NOT the front page then execute this code", `!is_home` being the way PHP/Wordpress checks if something is NOT true.

For the styling, you can add a class to the `<p>` tag in your code, like this:

`$content .= '<p class="my-date-style"> Posted '.date('F j, Y').'&nbsp;'.'</p>';`

Then add this to your CSS file:

```
.my-date-style {
  color: blue;
}
```

Without seeing the rest of the code it's difficult to say for sure, but this should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Definitely in the right direction! Couple of adjustments made possible by you: changed .date to .get_the_date (before it was just displaying today's date, which I didn't notice before); took away !is_front_page() && !is_home() but still wasn't working... then I took away is_singular() and it worked; and your styling advice worked! Thanks for your help :)